# ¿Cómo puedo listar ficheros de una carpeta que su ruta es introducido por usuario en java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Show ");
    File f = new File(".");
    String[] arxius = f.list();

    for (int i=0; i<arxius.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arxius[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n#####################\n");
    System.out.println("Returns");
    File[] roots = File.listRoots();

    for (File root : roots){
        System.out.println(root);
    }
   }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo listar ficheros de una carpeta que su ruta es introducido por usuario en java?

Answer (score 1):

Para eso tienes que obtener la ruta absoluta de la ruta introducida por el usuario. Esto lo puedes lograr utilizando la clase **Path** de Java.

Para obtener la ruta absoluta tienes que utilizar el método `toAbsolutePath()` de la clase Path.

```
// ...

String archivo = scanner.nextLine();

// Obtienes la ruta introducida por el usuario
Path path = Paths.get(archivo);

// Obtienes la ruta absoluta de la ruta introducida por el usuario
Path rutaAbsoluta = path.toAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(rutaAbsoluta);

// ...
```

Puedes obtener un `String` de la ruta absoluta utilizando el método `toString()` del objeto de tipo `Path`.

```
String rutaAbsolutaString = rutaAbsoluta.toString();
```

Después puedes listar los ficheros de la carpeta como lo estabas haciendo.

---

> También puedes obtener la ruta absoluta utilizando el método `toRealPath()` de la clase `Path`. La única diferencia de este método comparado con el método `toAbsolutePath()` es que este método lanza una `NoSuchFileException` si la ruta introducida por el usuario no existe. Si implementas este método recuerda también capturar la `IOExeption`, de lo contrario se generara un error en tiempo de compilación. En la documentación de Java se explica mejor el funcionamiento de este método.

Referencia:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html#convert

Answer (score 0):

Esto te va a funcionar:

```
System.out.println("Ingrese la ruta de archivos: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String directorio = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("El directorio elegido es " + directorio);
File folder = new File(directorio);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("Archivo " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Carpeta " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: El archive debe ser introduction por el usuario como comenta el OP.